# Discord JavaScript (node:1068) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated

Tags: discord.js, message

So i have been trying to get n simple pong message when I  run the command, however I get this error

CODE:

```
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const prefix = '/stock';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('StockBot is online!');

});

client.on('message', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    } });
```

I blocked away my login code.

ERROR:

> (node:1068) DeprecationWarning: The message event is deprecated. Use
> messageCreate instead (Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show
> where the warning was created)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rJUyz.png)

Comment: Read more about the deprecated message access: https://support-dev.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/4404772028055-Message-Content-Access-Deprecation-for-Verified-Bots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since v13, the `message` event has been deprecated. Replace your code with this:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({ intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES] });

const prefix = '/stock';

client.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('StockBot is online!');

});

client.on('messageCreate', message =>{
    if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    if(command === 'ping'){
        message.channel.send('pong!');
    } });
```

Comment: Instead of giving me an error it. this time it doesn't work and doesn't give me an error. i type /stock ping. and it does nothing

Comment: Ife changed the prefix and now it works thanks for your help sir!